# build multi associated array with unknown depth

Tags: ruby

I have sorted strings from a `directorylisting` and need to make nested JSON out of it.

Input:

```
/
/caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip/
/caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip/shaders
/caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip/shared
/caseIH1660byStevie.zip/
/caseIH1660byStevie.zip/shaders
/caseIH1660byStevie.zip/shared
/caseIH1660byStevie.zip/shared/lightPattern
```

Expected output

```
[ 
  name: "/", children: [
    name: "caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip", children: [
      name: "shaders", children: [],    
      name: "shared", children: [] ],
    name: "caseIH1660byStevie.zip", children: [
      name: "shaders", children: [],    
      name: "shared", children: [] ],

# ...
```

I struggle building up that array.

First level is obviously easy.

```
 if file == "/"
    tree["root"][file] = {name: file, children: {}}
  else
    parent = file.path.split("/").reject!(&:blank?) 
    # ...
```

My problem here is, that `parent` is `caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip`
i can go with `tree["root"][parent.first] =` 
but what if parent is 2 (or 3) elements long , like `["caseIH130SeriesbyStevie.zip", "shaders"]`

I then need to access `tree["root"][parent.first][:children][parent.second] = {}`
the whole thing can go probpably 8 levels deep.

Do i miss something or is that kind of difficult ?

### Summary / tl;dr

turn  `"a/b/c/d"` into
`["a", child: ["b", child: ["c", child: ["d", child: []]]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but I think it can be helpful :

```
class TakeSubs
    def initialize(string)
        @arr = string.split('/')
    end

    def get_it(i=0)
        element = @arr[i]
        if element 
            [element, Hash[:child, get_it(i+1)]]
        else
            []
        end
    end

end 

res = TakeSubs.new('a/b/c')
p res.get_it
 #=> ["a",  {:child => ["b",  {:child => ["c", {:child => []}]}]}]
```

Comment: yeah, basic recursion i guess :)